# Understanding the claim: "...then for a sufficiently small $h\gt 0$, $f$ will be continuous on $[a,a+h]$ and differentiable on $(a,a+h)$"

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

There is a reoccurring claim that is made in several of my book's proofs. I would like to know if I am correctly identifying the derivation of this claim. It reads as follows:

> Suppose that $f$ is continuous at $a$, and that $f'(x)$ exists for all $x$ in some interval containing $a$, except perhaps for $x=a$. **Then, for a sufficiently small $h\gt 0$, $f$ will be continuous on $[a,a+h]$ and differentiable on $(a,a+h)$ (a similar assertion holds for sufficiently small $h \lt 0$).**

The purpose of this conclusion, where continuity is defined with a closed interval and differentiability is defined with an open interval (involving the same end points), is to invoke this book's Mean Value Theorem, which is derived from this book's Rolle's Theorem.

Rolle's Theorem is written as:

> If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$, and $f(a)=f(b)$, then there is a number $x$ in $(a,b)$ such that $f'(x)=0$.

---

As to the initial claim that I am interested in, is *this* the correct justification for the claim? Or am I missing something:

Consider some interval $I$ that contains $a$. This interval could be opened, closed, or mixed where $c \lt a \lt d$.

1. $(c,d)$
2. $[c,d]$
3. $[c,d)$
4. $(c, d]$

For all $x\neq a$ in this interval, $f'(x)$ exists. Now, consider the closed interval $J \subset I$, defined as: $\left[a-\frac{|c-a|}{2},a+\frac{|d-a|}{2}\right]$.  Because $J \subset I$, $f$ is differentiable at every element $x \neq a$ in $J$. This means that $f$ is continuous at every element $x\neq a$ in $J$. Further, if $f$ is differentiable at every $x \neq a$ in $J$, a closed interval, then $f$ is differentiable at every element $x \neq a$ in $J'$ , the open interval version of $J$...i.e. $J'=\left( a-\frac{|c-a|}{2},a+\frac{|d-a|}{2}\right)$. Remembering that $f$ is continuous at $a$, we can then make the following two claims:

**A**: $f$ is continuous at every element in $\left[a,a+\frac{|d-a|}{2}\right]$, and $f$ is differentiable at every element in $\left(a, a+\frac {|d-a|}{2}\right)$.

**B**:  $f$ is continuous at every element in $\left[a-\frac{|c-a|}{2},a\right]$, and $f$ is differentiable at every element in $\left(a-\frac {|c-a|}{2},a\right)$.

If we wanted to make these intervals symmetric, we could use $\min\left(\frac{|d-a|}{2},\frac{|c-a|}{2}\right)$ in our definition of these sub-intervals.

At any rate, **A:** will dictate the "sufficiently small $h \gt 0$" and **B:** will dictate the "sufficiently small $h\lt 0$".

Is this the basic idea?

Comment: This claim should follow from the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of a limit.

Comment: @RolandKillian I’m not sure I follow. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Not an answer to your question but this is very confusing for the reader since you write things like "every element $x\in J$ is differentiable". It's $f$ that's differentiable at $x$, surely?

Comment: @ancientmathematician sorry for the sloppiness - I will make the adjustments now.

Comment: I think your argument is OK. Personally I'd ditch the cases by observing at the very start that we only need to argue about $(c,d)$. And then choose $h_1:=\frac{1}{2}(d-a)$ and show that continuity holds on all $[a,a+h]$ with $h<h_1$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thank you for the input - could you clarify why I would not have to make an argument for the mixed cases? Or, I guess, maybe your point is that *portions* of "the approach" I use in the $(c,d)$ case could be applied to the mixed cases...and therefore I need not concern myself with other cases?

Comment: Quite simply if you can prove this about $(c,d)$ you can prove it about $[c,d)$ and all the others.